# How to get the mode of distribution in scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

The `scipy.stats` library has functions to find the mean and median of a fitted distribution but not mode.

If I have the parameters of a distribution after fitting to data, how can I find the `mode` of the fitted distribution?

Comment: @MayowaAyodele: Why do you refer to _this same post_ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59662920/how-to-get-the-mode-of-distribution-in-scipy-stats) in your comment? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I don't get your wrong, you want to find the mode of fitted distributions instead of mode of a given data. Basically, we can do it with following 3 steps.

## Step 1: generate a dataset from a distribution

```
from scipy import stats
from scipy.optimize import minimize
# generate a norm data with 0 mean and 1 variance
data = stats.norm.rvs(loc= 0,scale = 1,size = 100)
data[0:5]
```

Output:

> array([1.76405235, 0.40015721, 0.97873798, 2.2408932 , 1.86755799])

## Step 2: fit the parameters

```
# fit the parameters of norm distribution
params = stats.norm.fit(data)
params
```

Output:

> (0.059808015534485, 1.0078822447165796)

Note that there are 2 parameters for `stats.norm`, i.e. `loc` and `scale`. For different dist in `scipy.stats`, the parameters are different. I think it's convenient to store parameter in a tuple and then unpack it in the next step.

## Step 3: get the mode(maximum of your density function) of fitted distribution

```
# continuous case
def your_density(x):
    return -stats.norm.pdf(x,*paras)
minimize(your_density,0).x
```

Output:

> 0.05980794

Note that a `norm` distribution has `mode` equals to `mean`. It's a coincidence in this example.

**One more thing** is that `scipy` treats continuous dist and discrete dist different(they have different father classes), you can do the same thing with following code on discrete dists.

```
## discrete dist, example for poisson
x = np.arange(0,100) # the range of x should be specificied
x[stats.poisson.pmf(x,mu = 2).argmax()] # find the x value to maximize pmf
```

Out:

> 1

You can it try with your own data and distributions!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I understand the logic you have used here. But I am not sure why in my case the pdf function is always returning me 0. I have a gamma distribution fitted to data. Other functions like ppf, mean and var are returning the correct values but pdf returns me 0. And if i try to minimize it, the solution returned is the initial starting point of optimization. Not sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: @AdnanTamimi show me your data and code, I think you maybe misuse the `.pdf` function

Comment: The parameters of the distribution p = [1.0903919789648953, 186586.34341665, 102313.74542487558]

from scipy.stats import gamma


def your_density(x):
    return -gamma.pdf(x,*p)


minimize(your_density, 0).x

Comment: Unable to post the data here due to character limitation

Comment: Your x range should be larger than `scale`, which means `x0` should larger than 186586.[See](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html)

Comment: This only works for discrete distributions if you know the possible range of values apriori. How do you conduct a search if your distribution is unknown, and might be unbounded or non-integer? It would be nice to have a general method.

Comment: In parametric statistics, we assume data obey some distribution and only the parameter of distribution is _unknown_. Insead of parametric statistics, there are many __nonparametric__ statistical methods which can estimate population median based on samples. The simplistic one is using sample median to estimate population median.